# Initialize Google Earth Engine API with a proxy server

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, google-earth-engine

After authentication, the earth engine API connects with the servers successfully with the Initialize() function.

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
```

However, as soon as I start using a proxy server, the initialization fails and generates the following error.

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I have tried modifying the IPython notebook server environment

```
import os
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'my_proxy_id:proxy_port'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'my_proxy_id:proxy_port'
```

Still the ee library fails to connect with the servers. How do I update the proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

For windows10, write your proxy information in the console as follows:

```
> set http_proxy='my_proxy_id:proxy_port'
> set https_proxy='my_proxy_id:proxy_port'
```

Then get into the python environment and check the ee.Initialize():

```
> python
>>> import ee
>>> ee.Initialize()
```

If no error prints out, then the proxy setting is ok.